# Group by multiple values and break down to weekly periods

Tags: c#, linq

I'm still learning LINQ and have a task where I need to group Booking objects by four properties and then by weekly intervals depending on the input timerange.

```
public class Booking
{
    public string Group { get; set; }
    public BookingType Type { get; set; }
    public BookingStatus Status { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public bool Notification { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

Let's say we have the following Bookings:

```
        IList<Booking> Bookings = new List<Booking>
        {
            new Booking{Group = "Group1", Type = BookingType.Online, Status = BookingStatus.New, Price = 150, Date = new DateTime(2012,06,01)},
            new Booking{Group = "Group1", Type = BookingType.Online, Status = BookingStatus.New, Price = 100, Date = new DateTime(2012,06,02)},
            new Booking{Group = "Group1", Type = BookingType.Online, Status = BookingStatus.New, Price = 200, Date = new DateTime(2012,06,03)},

            new Booking{Group = "Group2", Type = BookingType.Phone, Status = BookingStatus.Accepted, Price = 80, Date = new DateTime(2012,06,10)},
            new Booking{Group = "Group2", Type = BookingType.Phone, Status = BookingStatus.Accepted, Price = 110, Date = new DateTime(2012,06,12)},

            new Booking{Group = "Group3", Type = BookingType.Store, Status = BookingStatus.Accepted, Price = 225, Date = new DateTime(2012,06,20)},

            new Booking{Group = "Group3", Type = BookingType.Store, Status = BookingStatus.Invoiced, Price = 300, Date = new DateTime(2012,06,21)},
            new Booking{Group = "Group3", Type = BookingType.Store, Status = BookingStatus.Invoiced, Price = 140, Date = new DateTime(2012,06,22)},
        };
```

That would result in the following lines on the final printout:

```
                                        Week 22     Week 23     Week 24     Week 25     Week 26
                                        May28-Jun3  Jun4-10     Jun11-17    Jun18-24    Jun25-Jul1
            Group   Type    Status      Cnt. Price  Cnt. Price  Cnt. Price  Cnt. Price  Cnt. Price
            ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            Group1  Online  New         3   450     0   0       0   0       0   0       0   0
            Group2  Phone   Accepted    0   0       1   80      1   110     0   0       0   0
            Group3  Store   Accepted    0   0       0   0       0   0       1   225     0   0       
            Group3  Store   Invoiced    0   0       0   0       0   0       2   440     0   0
```

I have created 2 additional classes to represent a line with the possibility to include any number of weeks:

```
 public class GroupedLine
{
    public string Group { get; set; }
    public BookingType Type { get; set; }
    public BookingStatus Status { get; set; }
    public List<WeeklyStat> WeeklyStats { get; set; } 
}

public class WeeklyStat
{
    public DateTime WeekStart { get; set; }
    public decimal Sum { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

If I have the following time period:

```
        var DateFrom = new DateTime(2012, 05, 28);
        var DateTo = new DateTime(2012, 7, 01);
```

Firstly, I need to identify what weeks are necessary in the statistics: in this case week 22-26.

For that I have the following code:

```
        var DateFrom = new DateTime(2012, 05, 28);
        var DateTo = new DateTime(2012, 7, 01);

        var firstWeek = GetFirstDateOfWeek(DateFrom, DayOfWeek.Monday);
        IList<DateTime> weeks = new List<DateTime> { firstWeek };

        while(weeks.OrderByDescending(w => w).FirstOrDefault().AddDays(7) <= DateTo)
        {
            weeks.Add(weeks.OrderByDescending(w => w).FirstOrDefault().AddDays(7));
        }
```

And now, I'd need some LINQ magic to do the grouping both by the 4 properties and the aggregation (count of bookings and sum of prices) for the weeks.

I can attach code sample of the LINQ I got so far tomorrow, as I don't have access to it now.
Sorry for the long post, hope it's clear what I mean.

Edit: 2012-11-07
I have to modify the question a bit, so that the grouped weeks only include those weeks, that actually have data. 
Updated example output:

```
                                        May28-Jun3  Jun4-10     Jun18-24    
            Group   Type    Status      Cnt. Price  Cnt. Price  Cnt. Price  
            ---------------------------------------------------------------
            Group1  Online  New         3   450     0   0       0   0       
            Group2  Phone   Accepted    0   0       1   80      0   0       
            Group3  Store   Accepted    0   0       0   0       1   225             
            Group3  Store   Invoiced    0   0       0   0       2   440
```

In this case there were no Bookings in period Jun 11-17 and Jun25-Jul1 so they are omitted from the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will get all data

```
var query = from b in Bookings
            where b.Date >= dateFrom && b.Date <= dateTo
            group b by new { b.Group, b.Type, b.Status } into g
            select new GroupedLine()
            {
                Group = g.Key.Group,
                Type = g.Key.Type,
                Status = g.Key.Status,
                WeeklyStats = (from b in g
                                let startOfWeek = GetFirstDateOfWeek(b.Date)
                                group b by startOfWeek into weekGroup
                                orderby weekGroup.Key
                                select new WeeklyStat() 
                                {
                                    WeekStart = weekGroup.Key,
                                    Count = weekGroup.Count(),
                                    Sum = weekGroup.Sum(x => x.Price)

                                }).ToList()
            };
```

I leave UI output to you :)

This will also return WeekStats for all weeks (with 0 values, if we do not have booking groups on some week):

```
// sequence contains start dates of all weeks
var weeks = Bookings.Select(b => GetFirstDateOfWeek(b.Date))
                    .Distinct().OrderBy(date => date);

var query = from b in Bookings
            group b by new { b.Group, b.Type, b.Status } into bookingGroup
            select new GroupedLine()
            {
               Group = bookingGroup.Key.Group,
               Type = bookingGroup.Key.Type,
               Status = bookingGroup.Key.Status,
               WeeklyStats = (from w in weeks
                              join bg in bookingGroup 
                              on w equals GetFirstDateOfWeek(bg.Date) into weekGroup
                              orderby w
                              select new WeeklyStat() 
                              {
                                  WeekStart = w,
                                  Count = weekGroup.Count(),
                                  Sum = weekGroup.Sum(b => b.Price)    
                              }).ToList()
            };
```

Keep in mind, that if you need date filter (from, to), then you need to apply it both to `weeks` query and `bookings` query.

Comment: Hey, this looks great! Just a small thing: might be easier for UI purposes if all GroupedLines would have WeeklyStats for all the weeks (even with 0 values).. How would I need to modify the query?

Comment: Hello again! One additional task I have and I seem to block when it comes to linq, is to create a summary line with the sum of sums and counts, this time grouped by the weeks they are in. So e.g. week 25 would result in Total: Count: 3 Sum: 665. It could take the result of previous query or just the bookings again...

Comment: @akrobet I think you can create new question for this :) Also specify there what have you tried to do

Comment: Heh, after some coffee I figured out it's basically the same query as the WeeklyStats from your solution, without grouping them first...

Comment: @akrobet congratulations :) You did one more step in knowing Linq!

Comment: Hello again. As it turns out the requirements changed for this feature, now requiring that only those weeks are shown that there are  entries to. This again, causes me a headache. The first solution is almost correct, it's just that if there is data for one WeeklyStats the others should also include that week (with no data.) So basically the Week should only be completely left out, when none of the GroupedLines have entries to that week period. Hope it makes sense?..

Comment: @akrobet actually it's not very clear what you need. Some table representation should help. Also I think it's another question :)

Comment: As it is a quite specific question I didn't want to open a new question and explain the whole situation. I have updated the main question with the example at the end. I hope it's understandable. Your help is much appreciated :)

Comment: @akrobet my second solution do exactly that thing - only weeks, which have bookings will be selected there.

Comment: Ahh, sorry for that... Since this is a scaled down problem, the actual domain classes are more complicated and I used something else for getting the weeks... With your solution it works perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = Bookings.GroupBy(book => new GroupedLine()
{
    Group = book.Group,
    Type = book.Type,
    Status = book.Status
})
.Select(group => new
{
    Line = group.Key,
    Dates = group.GroupBy(book => GetWeekOfYear(book.Date))
        .Select(innerGroup => new
        {
            Week = innerGroup.Key,
            Count = innerGroup.Count(),
            TotalPrice = innerGroup.Sum(book => book.Price)
        })
});

public static int GetWeekOfYear(DateTime date)
{
    return date.DayOfYear % 7;
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the answer, chose @lazyberezovsky's because it worked out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

This variant generates "empty" spots for weeks with no data:

```
// I group by week number, it seemed clearer to me , but you can change it
var firstWeek = cal.GetWeekOfYear(DateFrom, dfi.CalendarWeekRule, dfi.FirstDayOfWeek);
var lastWeek  = cal.GetWeekOfYear(DateTo, dfi.CalendarWeekRule, dfi.FirstDayOfWeek);

var q = from b in Bookings
        group b by new { b.Group, b.Type, b.Status }
        into g
        select new 
        {
            Group = g.Key,
            Weeks = 
                from x in g
                select new 
                { 
                    Week = cal.GetWeekOfYear(x.Date,
                                             dfi.CalendarWeekRule, 
                                             dfi.FirstDayOfWeek), 
                    Item = x 
                }   
        } into gw
        from w in Enumerable.Range(firstWeek, lastWeek-firstWeek+1) 
        select new 
        { 
            gw.Group,
            Week = w,
            Item = from we in gw.Weeks
                   where we.Week == w
                   group we by we.Item.Group into p 
                   select new 
                   {
                       p.Key,
                       Sum = p.Sum (x => x.Item.Price),
                       Count = p.Count()
                   }
        };
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, chose @lazyberezovsky's because it was more clear to me.

Comment: No problem, actually I realized I didn't know about a small detail that in @lazyberezovsky's answer is clear, and it helps building a cleaner expression, I learned something new :)